# Pycharm shows .whl file as text file

Tags: pycharm, file-format

The problem that is repeatedly being faced is that pycharm tends to read and display a different format file with a completely different format. This QA gives step by step solution to resolve this issue for any of the formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `File` > `Settings` > `Editor` > `FileTypes`

From this screen you have two lists. Go to `recognised file types` and select text

Then from the bottom menu scroll to .whl format or the one which you want not to be read as text and select it. 
Now click the `minus sign (-)` on the right and click OK.

Comment: This problem was making my pip install command for .whl files fail and I didnt understand this could be the reason. I noticed it and now half my project issues are already resolved!